# "by walk" or "by foot" when travelling by walking

Tags: word-choice, prepositional-phrases

We can say "by car", "by bike", "by bus", "by train" and "by flight" when we're traveling by a transportation vehicle. But what if we're traveling by walking, what term should we say?

A few possibilities (in my idea):

- "by foot"
- "by feet"
- "by walk"
- "by walking"

Which term would be the best for concatenating with the preposition "by"?

Comment: Related: [Is "walk on foot" acceptable?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/55234/is-walk-on-foot-acceptable?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's *by air* rather than *by flight,* but **on foot** (and *on horseback*).

From other comments, it appears that some people do find *by foot* idiomatic. [Google Ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=by+foot&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3) shows the usage increasing during the 20th century - a lot of the early references are false positives.

Comment: *By* is a flexible preposition. “By train, plane, and automobile” is almost a stock phrase. A team of rescuers once went *By Dogsled for Byrd” to rescue the Admiral from the South Pole.  I have no problems with going somewhere on foot or by foot, or by rowboat or kayak or helicopter or wheelbarrow or even by stealth. But, as @Kate says, *by flight* is not idiomatic